# Replacement for picins, for wrapping text around some construct within multicols?

Tags: multicol, wrapfigure, picins

Within the `multicols` environment I would like to wrap text around a makebox construct. The description of `picins` in *The LaTeX Companion*, 2nd ed., makes it sound ideal, but it's no longer being distributed with TeXLive and I'd prefer to use something in the standard installation.

I've tried `wrapfig`, but it does not seem to work inside the `multicols` environment.

I've tried `picinpar`, but it provides a box around the construct, which I don't want. [I fixed an earlier justification problem by adding `ragged2e`.]

`floatflt` is also not standardly installed, it seems.

---

For illustration:

```
\usepackage{multicol}   % allows multicols
\usepackage{picinpar}   % allows window
\usepackage{wrapfig}        % allows wrapfigure and wraptable
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % fixes justification problem in window

\newcommand{\lorip}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. }

\begin{multicols*}{2}{
 \vspace{6pt}
 \begin{window}[0,l,%
  \fbox{Headword here},]
  \textbf{\small{\textsf{POS}}}\RaggedRight\textrm{. \lorip}
 \end{window}

 \vspace{6pt}
 \begin{wraptable}[2]{l}{0pt}
  \centering
   \fbox{Headword here}
 \end{wraptable}
 \textbf{\small{\textsf{POS}}}\textrm{. \lorip}
}
\end{multicols*}
```

`picinpar` first, with box; `wrapfig` second, doesn't work in multicols:
[image: picinpar and wrapfig results]

Any other suggestions?

---

**Edit**: I've fixed the earlier justification problem with package `ragged2e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like a box around the headword why do you put a box around? Just remove the `\fbox` command and your problem is solved.
Just have a look at http://ctan.org/pkg/picinpar. There you can read that one should use the picins- instead the legacy picinpar-package.

Why you don't want to use the picins-package? Just because it isn't distributed with your favorite distribution? If the package is able to do what you want just use it! I think many LaTeX users have their own *non standard* packages repository which is filled with packages written by them self, friends, colleagues or by their employers. A lot of my LaTeX projects wouldn't play without adding some extra packages.

Feel free to use *non standard* packages!

Comment: Thanks. I just realized the same thing and posted a note, too.

Comment: To reply to your question about `picins`, I did install it, and it is very nice. The reason I prefer to stick with a standard installation is that I work on many platforms and try to avoid having to replicate a manual installation on each. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I used `\fbox`, which draws an actual box around its contents, and should have used `\mbox`, which draws none. It had nothing to do with `picinpar`.